# Custom Paypal Form in HTML dreamweaver IPN

Tags: html, paypal-ipn, dreamweaver

Im trying to make a paypal form to submit "Username"  to my IPN,
so it edits my account via IPN (witch I have setup)

this is my form so far but when i click "buynow" button it takes me to my paypalaccount not to the paypal checkout. anyone had experience on this?

my form code:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
  <input type="hidden" name="business" value="myeamial@gmail.com">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="AUD">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="T-Shirt">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="10.00">

    <input type="hidden" name="on1" value="custom">Username</td>
    </p>
    <form name="_xclick" action="https://www.paypal.com/au/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <td>
      <p>
        <input type="text" name="os1" maxlength="200">
    </p></td>
    <td>
    <input type="image" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_AU/i/btn/x-click-but01.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: Maybe this is the correct hyperlink `https://ipnpb.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr` [IPN implementation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNImplementation/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `action` value to `https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr`

```
<form name="_xclick" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="on1" value="custom">Username</td>
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="myeamial@gmail.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="AUD">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="T-Shirt">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="10.00">
    <td>
        <p>
            <input type="text" name="os1" maxlength="200">
        </p>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="image" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_AU/i/btn/x-click-but01.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi their tried the out Still get taken to https://www.paypal.com/myaccount/home   I rather there then getting taken to a purchase page.  (yes myemail@gmail.com is my real email on my page)

Comment: @ZakWilliams That would happen if your action is set to `https://paypal.com/......` vs `https://www.paypal.com/.......`.